# How can I convert this SQL to LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-sql

I've created a code-first database and the question is that I'm having some difficulty transcribing this SQL statement into the C# code.

Below there's the SQL statement that I require help on adapting and the tables that I currently use. The objective of this SQL Query is that on the table TableViewedMessageLog is a record of which user saw which message and the desired effect is to select all messages Non-Read (which information is stored on this table -- TableViewMessageLogs) to an certain user.

http://gyazo.com/0105c0959bdd2930272bf5c07a112a11

```
select * from TableMessages tm
where tm.Id not in (select tv.Message_Id from TableViewedMessageLogs as tv
where tv.User_Email = 'asd@asd')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var data = (from e in context.TableMessages
            where context.TableViewedMessageLogs
                     .Where(x => x.User_Email == 'asd@asd')
                     .Select(x => x.Message_Id).Contains(e.Id) == false
            select e)
           .ToList();
```

Comment: This is just translation of the given query, I don't know what you are exactly doing database.

Answer (score 2):

Try this query:

```
var data = from f in context.TableMessages
           where f.id !=
           (
               from fb in TableViewedMessageLogs 
               where User_Email == 'asd@asd'
               select fb.Message_Id
           )
           select f;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this to prevent a sub query, providing better performance and makes it a lot easier to understand what's happening:

```
var viewedLogs = context.TableViewedMessageLogs.Where(w => w.User_Email = 'asd@asd');
var result = context.TableMessages.Where(w => !viewedLogs.Contains(w.Id));
```